# Why is feed subscription updating UI binding only on first ‘child added’ event and not after?

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Scenario/Problem:

- trying to reproduce Firebase's friendlyPix demo ([samples page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/samples/)) but as Angular 1 app.
- home feed lists the all the posts that a) current user created b) and/or his/her
  following users created
- I am able to get all the new posts once they are created(realtime) to update the feed in the Firebase realtime database on every realtime new post by a user and people the user is following.
- **Problem**:  **I am failing to get it to update the ui(view) after the first realtime new post** or in other words, after the first `child_added` event to `/feed/${this.currentUser.uid}/` ) in this case. So it makes shows the first realtime/live new post but not after.
- also, the `console.log` in the `_subscribeToHomeFeed` method shows that the results are a being resolved in the promise every time as well. But controller not receiving the data to update `vm.newPosts` Array.

// Router's resolve property

// this is actually in the ui-router resolve property

```
    _pixData: (friendlyFire)  => {
      friendlyFire.showHomeFeed().then(...{
            // see notes in method
            // returns _pixData for home feed _pixData[1] being the latestEntryId

        });
}
```

// HomeController relevant Code

```
.controller('HomeController', HomeController);

function HomeController(friendlyFire, _pixData) {
    vm.pixData = _pixData[0];  
    vm.latestEntryId = _pixData[1]; // data received from the promise of showHomeFeed method
    vm.newPosts = [];

    friendlyFire.subscribeToHomeFeed(vm.latestEntryId).then((postData) => {
        console.log(postData.key, 'post key');
        console.log(postData.val(), 'post value');

        var a = postData.key;
        var b = postData.val();
        vm.newPosts.push({'post key':a, 'post value': b});
    });
}
```

Service methods (friendlyFire)

```
// friendlyFire service - service that interacts with firebase


// showHomeFeed - called when user visits home route

showHomeFeed()( {
    ... update current feed 
    ... return a promise with posts data for feed & lastEntryId
}

subscribeToHomeFeed(latestEntryId) {
    console.log('subscribeToHomeFeed was this called');
    return this._subscribeToFeed(`/feed/${this.user.uid}`, latestEntryId, true);
}




// _subscribeToFeed: General feed subscription method to be used with wrapper methods like subscribeToHomeFeed

_subscribeToFeed(uri, latestEntryId = null, fetchPostDetails = false) {
    console.log('_subscribeToFeed was this called');
    var deferred = this.$q.defer();
    let feedRef = this.database.ref(uri);

    if (latestEntryId) {
        // Set up ref to only posts from last item posted and after
        feedRef = feedRef.orderByKey().startAt(latestEntryId);
    }

    feedRef.on('child_added', feedData => {

        console.log('feed  subscription child added called');

        // Update, but don't include posts after last item posted
        if (feedData.key !== latestEntryId) {
            console.log('feed subscription child added called inside if');

            // Get the postDetails using the feedData.key form posts uri where all posts details are stored


            this.database.ref(`/posts/${feedData.key}`).once('value').then((results) => {

                // NOTE: This is logging in the console with info even after 1st upload(new post/child added)
                console.log(results, 'results inside subscribe to homefeed');


                // Store in the  promise
                deferred.resolve(results);
            });
        }
    });

    // store ref in order for later clean up and end listeners when not in use 
    this.firebaseRefs.push(feedRef);

    // Return the promise to be used in the contoller 
    return deferred.promise;
}
```